# How to charge the iPhone If I have enabled the accessories settings on and the battery is dead?

Tags: iphone, charging

I have enabled the USB accessories option in the Touch ID & Passcode option and now my battery is dead and my iPhone is not charging since I have turned on the Accessories option.

Comment: Can you add some details about the relation you see between the UBS Accessories option and the iPhone not charging? If the battery is empty, it may take a few minutes before you see any effect from charging the phone.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's own documentation about USB Accessory setting, you can still charge your phone from a Mac with the setting active.

https://support.apple.com/HT208857

> Even if you don’t unlock your iPhone, iPad or iPod touch, your device
> still charges as usual when it’s connected to a USB power adapter.

However, my own experience has been variable in this regard. If it's really not working (and you may have to leave it some time before your phone comes back to life), then you'll need to charge it from a 'wall', rather than via a Mac.